# powershell script to convert svg images to png not working

Tags: powershell, svg, png

I have a file of svg images which I want to convert into png format. I used the following PowerShell script:

```
param(
[string]$path = 'C:\motif3',
[string]$exec = 'C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe')

foreach ($filename in Get-ChildItem $path) {
    if ($filename.toString().EndsWith('.svg')) {        

    $targetName = $filename.BaseName + ".png";

    echo "Converting $filename ..."

    $command = "& `"$exec`" -z -e `"$targetName`" -w 64 `"$filename`""; 
    Invoke-Expression $command;        
}
}
```

I ran the script successfully but it didn't convert the image.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Did you get an error, if so what was it?

Comment: Do you have inkscape installed? Can you successfully convert files from Inkscape's GUI?

Comment: Have you tried using $filename=$filename.fullname and $targetName = $filename.replace('.svg','.png'). It might be having some issues with relative file names.

Comment: @Shadowzee Yes. It worked. Thank you. But its showing a blank image.

Comment: @JasonBoyd The svg images are converted to png but all are blank images.

Answer (score 0):

Very bad necroing. But with the lastest version I was able to do this with the following line:

`inkscape --export-type='png' --export-filename='$targetName' $fileName`